# Android facebook audience network show native ad

Tags: android, facebook, native, ads, audience

Is it true?To show native ad from facebook audience network,we must install facebook app on our mobile phone of Android?When i test in my developing app,there is no ad to show whithout facebook app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No – the Audience Network is a separate library in the Facebook SDK
>   which does not require Facebook Login. Aside from the integration
>   steps indicated in the getting started guide, no other libraries or
>   setup is required.

Note: **...no other libraries or setup is required.** in the above quoted from documentation.

[Refer This Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/faq#a1)

Answer (score 3):

Facebook Audience Network displays live ads base on smart targeting. It tries to match user's device advertiser id to Facebook profile to deliver best suited ads to users.

Therefore To see Audience Network ads on your device, you must have the Facebook app installed and have logged in within the last 30 days. Also check to make sure you haven't opted out of ads on your device.

Comment: Yes I have realized that by experience. Is this a fact, I mean it is not said in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry. I realized my answer was wrong. It applied only to Facebook users, not to non-Facebook users.